# Какой инструмент существует для запуска тестов Selenium в headless режиме?

Tags: selenium, тестирование, headless

Какой инструмент существует для запуска **тестов Selenium** в **headless** режиме?
То есть: нажал на кнопку и без появления браузера идёт тестирование сайта. Без использования терминала для запуска. Это как в Selenium IDE - только без появления браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить флаг `"--headless"` в `ChromeOptions()`

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Окно браузера не будет появляться

Answer (score 0):

Решил всё с помощью Github Actions (ещё можно через Jenkins но не пробовал). Любой workflow можно перезапустить вручную.